# Join more then one table model using Eloquent ORM laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**This is my query:**

```
$batchDetails=BatchModel::join('class', 'batch.Class', '=', 'class.AutoID')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

**BatchModel:**

```
<?php
class BatchModel extends Eloquent
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'AutoID';
    protected $table = 'batch';  
    protected $fillable = array('Class','batch','Statedate','Enddate');

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function batch(){
        return $this->hasMany('BatchModel', 'Class');
    }

    public static $rules = array(     
        'Class' => 'required',         
        'batch' => 'required', 
        'Statedate' => 'required', 
        'Enddate' => 'required', 
        );

}
```

**ClassModel:**

```
<?php
class ClassModel extends Eloquent
{

    protected $primaryKey = 'AutoID';
    protected $created_at = 'CreatedAt';
    protected $updated_at = 'UpdatedAt';
    protected $table = 'class';
    protected $guarded = array('ClassName');
    protected $fillable = array('ClassName', 'ClassSection', 'ClassCode');

     public function classModel(){ 
        return $this->belongsTo('ClassModel', 'Class');
    }

    public $timestamps = true;


    public static $rules = array(
        'ClassName' =>  array('required', 'unique:class','regex:/^./'),
        'ClassSection' => 'required',
        'ClassCode' => array('required', 'unique:class')
                             );


}
```

I dont want to use the table name like "class and batch". I just want to use only the model name instead of table and table attributes.

So my questions is how can i make the above join query only using model names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Eloquent relations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships) for this.

```
class BatchModel extends Eloquent {
    public function classModel(){ // normally I'd use only "class" but that's a reserved word so..
        return $this->belongsTo('ClassModel', 'Class');
    }
}


class ClassModel extends Eloquent {
    protected $primaryKey = 'AutoID';
    public function batch(){
        return $this->hasMany('BatchModel', 'Class');
    }
}
```

Not sure if I got everything right, but it should be something along those lines. Now you can query it like this:

```
$batchDetails = BatchModel::with('classModel')->get();
```

Comment: I have follwing error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::classModel()"

Comment: But you did add the method `classModel()` to your `BatchModel`?

Comment: ya i have add method in class and batch model

Comment: Strange. That error usually only appears if the name in `with()` and the method name are not the same (or the method doesn't exist at all) Can you check for typos and also try: `$batch = BatchModel::first(); $batch->classModel();` and see if you get an error.

Comment: Where can i put? in controller?

Comment: ya i have this error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::classModel()"

Comment: Well then you either didn't add the method, added it to the wrong class or have some typo in the method name. I can't think of anything else. Can you maybe edit your question and add the current full `BatchModel`. Just copy paste the whole class...

Comment: I have update batchmodel and class model in my question.

Comment: Thanks. You have added the methods the wrong way around. `classModel()` belongs into the `BatchModel` class and `batch()` into `ClassModel`